# displaying variable in plot(varImp(randomForest_model))

Tags: random-forest

`varImpPlot(randomforest_model)` in randomForest displays default 30 top variables.
How do I display selected top variable only. for eg say top 18 .

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Needed to use `n.var` to display number of variables

```
varImpPlot(rf_fit,scale=TRUE,n.var=18)
```